# Using `immediate` for a cancel button but saving only some fields

Tags: jsf

I have a JSF 1.2 Form which is composed of several parts.

I have validation with `required` tag turned on.

I want to be able to clear a certain part of the form which has required fields so on the 'clear' button i used the `immediate` tag.

Now the challenge - When pressing the 'clear' button all the values that were filled since the last submission are restored to the last submitted state while I would like only the certain part of the form to be affected. (Meaning, all the values that are not in that part of the form should be sumbitted although the button pressed is `immediate`)

Is there a way to do this?

**EDIT** - Can I submit a value after every time it was filled? This might be a solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to take some fields along with the cancel button with `immediate="true"`, then you should also put `immediate="true"` on those fields.

If you want to skip validation on those fields as well, then you need to change `required="true"` to `required="#{empty param['formId:cancelButtonId']}"` so that it is only required when the cancel button is *not* been used to submit the form.

As to submitting the values on change, that's best to be achieved with ajax in combination with a value change listener. To achieve that you would need to upgrade to JSF 2.0 or to introduce an ajaxified JSF component library.